# Hibernate Composite primary key contains foreign key which is subset of other tables primary key, how to map?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

The scenario is as follows

Table A has a composite PK.

```
Table A 
-------- 
 a1 (pk)
 a2 (pk)
 a3 (pk)
 foo
 bar
 LastUpdateDate
 LastUpdateUser
========
```

Table B has a composite PK too which is actually subset of A's PK, here is working as FK as well. There is no forced FK constraint.

```
Table B 
-------- 
 a1 (fk,pk) 
 a2 (fk,pk) 
 foo
 bar 
 LastUpdateDate
 LastUpdateUser
========
```

I tried several ways, and none of them works. Can anyone tell a working Hibernate mapping solution? better in annotation style.

Thanks a lot.

Viv

Comment: Are you interested in using associations as PK for B? Basically, how do you want to relate A and B? What are types for a1,a2,a3?

Comment: I want to fetch Table B record for Table A, basically ManyToOne mapping in Table A entity. Is it possible? - Viv

Answer (score 0):

I can see following set up. Although it may be tricky to get to work and, based on my experience, it's unnecessary complexity.

```
class A implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private PK id = new PK();
   @Embeddable      
    public static final class PK implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne 
        @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="A1_COL", referencedColumnName = "id.a1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="A2_COL", referencedColumnName = "id.a2"),

        })
         B b;            
        @Basic String a3;
    }    
 }


class B implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private PK id = new PK();
   @Embeddable      
    public static final class PK implements Serializable {                    
        @Basic String a1;
        @Basic String a2;
        @Basic String a3;
    }    
 }
```

You should be able to access be via

```
a.getId().getB()
```

Add setters/getters as necessary.

Usually this type of problems requires a lot of trial and error, so don't expect this to work right away. But that should give you a direction for digging. Once you nail down final configuration, please add it to you question so somebody can benefit from it in future.